# Max Number of K sum pairs || Leetcode

Tags: c++, arrays, hashtable, unordered-map

https://leetcode.com/problems/max-number-of-k-sum-pairs/submissions/

You are given an integer array nums and an integer k.

In one operation, you can pick two numbers from the array whose sum equals k and remove them from the array.

Return the maximum number of operations you can perform on the array.

I am facing a very weird issue,

```
class Solution {
public:
    int maxOperations(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        unordered_map<int, int> seen;
        int ans = 0;
        int n=nums.size();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            seen[nums[i]]++;
        for(auto ele: seen)
        {
            int b=k-ele.first;
            if(b==ele.first){
                ans+=seen[b]/2;
                seen[b]=0;
            }
            else if(seen[b]>0 && seen[ele.first]>0)
            {
                ans+=min(seen[b],seen[ele.first]);
                seen[ele.first]=0;
                seen[b]=0;
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Test case:

```
[29,26,81,70,75,4,48,38,22,10,51,62,17,50,7,7,24,61,54,44,30,29,66,83,6,45,24,49,42,31,10,6,88,48,34,10,54,56,80,41,19]
12
```

If I am just using ordered map instead of unordered map then I am getting correct answer. I tried to debug it using many print statements, I could just come up some new elements are being added to my map seen when I am using the statement seen[b]>0 but the weird part is even though 6 is there in the map still it is not being traversed in case of unordered map which is leading to the issue.

Comment: Are you aware that a map's `operator[]` will insert an empty element into the map if the element doesn't exist?  If not, this is exactly why sites like LeetCode and similar random puzzle sites are not designed to teach C++.

Comment: Yes @PaulMcKenzie I am and i mentioned the same in my details section too. But I am not able to figure out why element 6 is not being traversed in unordered map while using an ordered map things work fine.

Comment: Stop using `operator[]` to determine if an entry is in the map, regardless of whether the map is `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.  Use `map::find()` instead.

Comment: Already, did that in map after iteration there are 60 elements though loop runs only 43 times. Also at any instance 6 is present in the map.